# Filter data returned by a function

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a very simple query, which looks like so:

```
SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).path as path FROM layer
```

It uses some library function which returns `integer[]` type. Data in the resulting table looks like:

```
{1}
{1,2}
{1}
```

I tried a lot of ways to filter this data - say, to get all rows which contain `{2}`. But I failed. The only query that works is this one:

```
SELECT path FROM (
    SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).path as path FROM layer_60_ 
) t WHERE path @> '{2}'::integer[]
```

But using a subquery in this case looks like overkill. Is there any possibility to filter it right away without a subquery? My own attempts ended in failure:

```
SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).path as path FROM layer_60_ WHERE path ... # indeed, wrong

SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).path as path FROM layer_60_ HAVING path ... # wrong

SELECT * FROM layer_60_ WHERE (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).path ... # does not work

SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).path as path FROM layer_60_ GROUP BY path HAVING path ... # wrong!!!
```

So, what is wrong with that and is there any simpler solution, than a subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a sub-query should not be of any concern to you. The planner will fold sub-queries into a single plan anyway. If a query is easier to construct, understand and maintain using a sub-query, then - by all means - go ahead. There is no performance penalty (unless you use [optimization barriers](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/)).

In your case, the function `ST_DumpPoints()` is a set-returning function, so you should really use it as a row source and then it becomes rather easy to do what you want without a sub-query:

```
SELECT p.path
FROM layer_60_, ST_DumpPoints(geom) p(path, geom)
WHERE p.path @> '{2}'::integer[];
```

The function is evaluated once for each of the rows from the preceding table and then the rows are joined as if there were a join condition specified. After that you can refer to the columns of the function output.

Comment: Would not it be better to use `ANY` instead of contains operator? Like `2 = ANY(p.path)`?